# Push Multi D Data into array without specifying index in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$result_array`, i am trying to push multi dimentional values into this array
without specifying the index as like below

```
$result_array[]["name"] = "Balan"
$result_array[]["active"] = true
```

But the resultant array looks like

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
  (
   "name" => Balan
  )
 [1] => Array
  (
   "active" => true
  )
)
```

But the result i would like to have is like below

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
  (
   "name" => Balan
   "active" => true
  )
)
```

Please note, i am aware i can initialize a `$key = 0` and increment it on each loop to
achieve this. But i would like to know how i can do this without using a separate variable and increment it.

Thanks.

Comment: Show original content of `$result_array`

Comment: The second code snippet at last is what i expect, the one above the last one is what generated when i push values as like show at first.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like  this..

```
<?php

$arr=Array(0 => Array("name" => 'Balan'),1 => Array("active" => "true"));
foreach($arr as $arr1)
{
    foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v)
    {
        $new_arr[0][$k]=$v;
    }
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Balan
            [active] => true
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
    $result_array[]["name"] = "Balan";

    end($result_array);       
    $key = key($result_array);

    $result_array[$key]["active"] = true;
```

Should be useful for someone..!!